# SQL Server CE - The column name is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce-4

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what this error means and how to fix it:

> The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = id ]

Here is the db schema:

`Staff`:

- `Id`: `int, not null, auto increment by 1, primary key`
- `username`: `varchar, not null`
- `name`: `varchar, not null`

And here is the insertion script:

```
String Insertion = "INSERT INTO Staff ([username], [name])
                    VALUES (@username, @name)";

SqlCeCommand InsertStaff = new SqlCeCommand(Insertion, connect);
InsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username.Text);
InsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name.Text);

InsertStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I've even tried including the `Id` column with no luck:

```
String Insertion = "INSERT INTO Staff ([Id], [username], [name])
                    VALUES (NULL, @username, @name)";

SqlCeCommand InsertStaff = new SqlCeCommand(Insertion, connect);
InsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username.Text);
InsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name.Text);

InsertStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have no idea what the issue is, it just keeps breaking. Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct case??? Id != id

Comment: Yeah man, double and triple checked. Still the same error, it's "Id"